# Scapy and Arguments

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to pass multiple arguments to a scapy script that I wrote (scapy1.py):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
from scapy.all import *

p=sr1(IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/TCP(dport=sys.argv[2]))
```

I execute this as:

```
./scapy1.py 192.168.1.100 80
```

This however does not execute properly and I get the errors below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scapy1.py", line 6, in <module>
    p=srp(IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/TCP(dport=sys.argv[2]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", line 198, in     __call__
    i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.fields[f] = self.get_field(f).any2i(self,fields[f])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 733, in any2i
    return self.any2i_one(pkt,x)        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 722, in any2i_one
    x = self.s2i[x]
KeyError: '22'
```

Any idea why this not working? I know the arguments are getting passed if I do a:

```
print sys.argv[1]
print sys.arvg[2]
```

Comment: `int(sys.argv[2])` will work, you don't need to change `sport`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `dport` for destination and convert it to int:

```
p=sr1(IP(dst=sys.argv[1])/TCP(dport=int(sys.argv[2])))
```

Comment: Whoops, thats a typo, but still happens with dport. Will give your suggestion a try.